# how to match value from db with substring with file name in python

Tags: python

i am trying to get user_name + father_name from db and match with substring with file names in directory. and then if files exist then update value in db. how to do this. Please don't mark it questened before. i need the answer.

i have tried so far

**data look like this**

```
file_names = ['amanatta.0.jpg', 'amanatta.1.jpg', 'amanatta.10.jpg', 'amanatta.11.jpg', 'amanatta.12.jpg',
                   'amanatta.13.jpg', 'amanatta.14.jpg', 'amanatta.15.jpg', 'amanatta.16.jpg', 'amanatta.2.jpg',
                   'amanatta.3.jpg', 'amanatta.4.jpg', 'amanatta.5.jpg', 'amanatta.6.jpg', 'amanatta.7.jpg',
                   'amanatta.8.jpg', 'amanatta.9.jpg', 'habibaman.0.jpg', 'habibaman.1.jpg', 'habibaman.10.jpg',
                   'habibaman.11.jpg', 'habibaman.12.jpg', 'habibaman.13.jpg', 'habibaman.14.jpg', 'habibaman.15.jpg',
                   'habibaman.16.jpg', 'habibaman.2.jpg', 'habibaman.3.jpg', 'habibaman.4.jpg', 'habibaman.5.jpg',
                   'habibaman.6.jpg', 'habibaman.7.jpg', 'habibaman.8.jpg', 'habibaman.9.jpg', 'luqmanaman.0.jpg',
                   'luqmanaman.1.jpg', 'luqmanaman.10.jpg', 'luqmanaman.11.jpg', 'luqmanaman.12.jpg',
                   'luqmanaman.13.jpg', 'luqmanaman.14.jpg', 'luqmanaman.15.jpg', 'luqmanaman.16.jpg',
                   'luqmanaman.2.jpg', 'luqmanaman.3.jpg', 'luqmanaman.4.jpg', 'luqmanaman.5.jpg',
                   'luqmanaman.6.jpg', 'luqmanaman.7.jpg', 'luqmanaman.8.jpg', 'luqmanaman.9.jpg']

    user_names =['habibaman', 'luqmanaman', 'amanatta']
```

**db**

```
table name -> users
column name -> [ u_misid, u_name, u_fname, u_dataset]
```

**code**

```
def updatestatus():
    query1 = "select `u_misid`, `u_name`, `u_fname` from users"
    cur.execute(query1)
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for item in rows:
        for (dirpath, dirnames, filename) in os.walk('modeldata/photosamples/'):
            fnl = item[1].lower() + item[2].lower()
            if filename[0].startswith("{0}".format(fnl)):
                query2 = "update users set `u_dataset`=%s where u_misid=%s"
                values = (1, item[0])
                cur.execute(query2, values)
                conn.commit()

updatestatus()
```

**if file_name(sub string) exist matching with user_name then update u_dataset in user table**

Comment: What is your question exactly?  I see a number of issues with your code, but nothing that I can say would mean it isn't doing what you want it to do.  Please add descriptions of the behavior you want and the behavior you're getting to your question.

Comment: actually i am trying to get names from db and then match those names with file names in directory. if the files exists, then update a column value in db

Comment: i have achieved this, but now i want to check if file does not exists then update column value in db, can any one help me?

Comment: One thing...you are testing `filename[0]`.  So you are only testing one file in each directory.  I would think you would want to iterate over all the files in the directory with `for fname in filename:`... (note that `filename` as third result from `os.walk` is a misleading name...should be `filenames`)

Comment: Again...please add the desired behavior and the behavior you are getting to your question.  You have to tell us what the problem is you are seeing with your code.  We don't have your database or your filesystem, so we can't reproduce your situation.  On top of that, it isn't at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: my data look like this, if names not match with file names, update column value, i have tried this, but set all values in column to specified value, for example if file exist then set value = 1,(working correctly), but if file not exists then set value = 0(not working).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229830/discussion-between-habib-ur-rehman-and-cryptofool).

Comment: i have tried (if not name.startswith("{0}".format(fnl))) , but set all values of u_dataset column to 0, i only want set those whose files does not exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have achieved this by putting an extra loop and looping through filename. code is given below.

**code**

```
def updatestatus():
    query1 = "select `u_misid`, `u_name`, `u_fname` from users"
    self.cur.execute(query1)
    rows = self.cur.fetchall()

    for item in rows:
        fnl = (item[1].lower() + item[2].lower() + item[0]).replace(" ", "")
        for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('modeldata/photosamples/'):
            status = False
            if len(filenames) <= 0:
                query4 = "update users set `u_dataset`=%s where u_misid=%s"
                values4 = (0, item[0])
                self.cur.execute(query4, values4)
                self.conn.commit()
                else:
                    for name in filenames:
                    if name.startswith("{0}".format(fnl)):
                        status = True
                        if status == True:
                            query2 = "update users set `u_dataset`=%s where u_misid=%s"
                            values = (1, item[0])
                            self.cur.execute(query2, values)
                            self.conn.commit()

                            break
                        else:
                            query3 = "update users set `u_dataset`=%s where u_misid=%s"
                            values3 = (0, item[0])
                            self.cur.execute(query3, values3)
                            self.conn.commit()
    threading.Timer(10, updatestatus).start()

updatestatus()
```

Comment: Ok, great!  So you answered your own question.  Or did you?  If you didn't, then please delete this "answer", as it isn'n an answer to the question, and put the information in your original question.

Comment: Absolutely this is an answer to my first problem, but now i am facing second problem.  first problem -> if file exists then set u_dataset = 1 (achieved this by adding an extra inner loop).                                                                                                               
second problem -> if file not exists then set u_dataset = 0 (not achieved yet)